# Axios promise chaining not working

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to use an apiclient that calls apicalls and use promise but I get the error:

```
"Cannot read property of 'then' of undefined"
```

I want the apiCalls to only "return" data which I have modified or gotten from the server, and the ApiClient to be able to call somewhere in my code:

```
const apiClient = new ApiClient()

apiClient.getCharacterOrders(character.character_id, character.access_token)
```

I will then send it via an event when it is processed. But the ApiClient never gets the data from the ApiCalls "return".

```
ApiClient file
-----------------------------------------------

import ApiCalls from './ApiCalls'

const apiCalls = new ApiCalls()

class ApiClient {

  getCharacterOrders (characterId, accessToken) {

    apiCalls.getCharacterOrders(characterId, accessToken)
      .then(response => {

        this.response = response.data

        console.log('Response ' + this.response)

        // Send this via an event somewhere

      }).catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)      
      })

  }
}

export default ApiClient




ApiCalls file
-----------------------------------------------


import {HTTP} from './axiosClient'

class ApiCalls {
  getCharacterOrders (characterId, accessToken) {
    HTTP.get('/characters/' + characterId + '/orders/?token=' + accessToken)
    .then(response => {

      this.response = response.data

      // Do stuff to data here

      return this.response

    }).catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)      
    })
  }

}

export default ApiCalls
```

Comment: Probaste simply returns the HTTP.get ()?

Comment: What 's in './axiosClient`?

Comment: `getCharacterOrders` does not `return` anything. Add `return` before `HTTP.get(...)`. Functions that don't have a `return` statement return `undefined` by default (hence you get the error *"Cannot read property of 'then' of **undefined**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding "return" in front of HTTP.get and removing "this.response" because it returned response.data.data